# How to add launcher.apk to the system/app in android firmware

Tags: android, libvlc, android-firmware

My app is running well when I added it in `data/app` location but when I pushed it in `system/app` it's not working properly, it throws the error

```
08-08 05:15:35.451: E/VLC/LibVLC(5116): Can't load vlcjni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vlcjni from loader 
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/app/myapp.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/myapp]: findLibrary returned null
```

I have successfully compiled libVlc for android and it's working fine except I mentioned above. Do I need to sign the myapp.apk with firmware key? Or is there any set of permissions that I need to add?

Comment: Can you trying pushing your vlcjni lib to /system/lib and try again after rebooting.

Comment: nice idea..but don't know how? because vlc is precompiled library I know how to use it in application lib but don't know how to use it in system lib

Comment: If this is precompiled *.so file, then push in /system/lib/ folder of device and inside your android.mk file add following lines   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := vlcjni
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: @AnkitSomani LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := vlcjni include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) where to add this at the start or end

Comment: End of the file should be good.

Comment: @AnkitSomani android.mk file has LOCAL_MODULE := libvlcjni can I put LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libvlcjni include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) instead LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := vlcjni include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58918/discussion-between-rahul-matte-and-ankitsomani).